# Appending a new row in the table

Tags: jquery

I have the two input fields.

```
<label>First Name:</label><input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname">
<label>Last Name:</label><input type="name" class="form-control" id="lname">
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Add</button>
```

I am trying to add the values to the table. With every time i click add button i need to insert values in new row:

```
<table class="table bordered" id="table">
   <thead><tr><td>S.N.</td><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td></tr></thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">
            <tr id="tr">
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <div id="showf"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="showl"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

This is what i have done. Jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '#add', function (e) 
{ 
    e.preventDefault();
    var fname=$('#fname').val();
    var lname=$('#lname').val();

    $('#tbody').append($('#tr').html());
    $('#showf').append(fname);
    $('#showl').append(lname);


});
```

the result is ok for the first column. And then next time i click on add button, the new row appears to be displaced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should append the entire tr.

This should be your html:

```
<table class="table bordered" id="table">
   <thead><tr><td>S.N.</td><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td></tr></thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">

        </tbody>
</table>
```

And your Jquery should be:

```
$(document).on('click', '#add', function (e) 
{ 
    e.preventDefault();
    var fname=$('#fname').val();
    var lname=$('#lname').val();

    $('#tbody').append('<tr><td>' + fname + '</td><td>' + lname + '</td></tr>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With regard to your code, I wouldn't recommend inserting elements that share the same `id` attribute.  Consider this alternative approach:

```
function addNameToTable($table, firstName, lastName) {
    var newRow = '<tr>';
    newRow += '<td></td>';
    newRow += '<td><div class="showf">' + firstName + '</div></td>';
    newRow += '<td><div class="showl">' + lastName + '</div></td>';
    newRow += '</tr>';
    $table.find('tbody').append(newRow);
}

$(document).on('click', '#add', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $table = $('#table');
    var firstName = $('#fname').val();
    var lastName = $('#lname').val();
    addNameToTable($table, firstName, lastName);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is take the last index of your HTML table.
For example if you have got 3 rows in table then use the eq() method of Jquery. 
Eg. Eq(2).. this will take you to the last node.

Then you can append whatever HTML you need..

**Here is the solution..**

```
$('#your_table > tbody > tr').eq(i-1).after(html);
```